# linking boost components - catkin error

Tags: ros, catkin, boost, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed most of the answers on how to link properly a library and still I cant compile my package with catkin_make, due to undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()`

Here is my the summary of my CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(pleora_polarcam)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lboost_system") 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lpthread")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  dynamic_reconfigure
  driver_base
  camera_info_manager
)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost 1.54 COMPONENTS log_setup log program_options thread REQUIRED)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES photonfocus_camera
  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport roscpp 
  DEPENDS system_lib
  DEPENDS Boost opencv 
)

include_directories(
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${EBUS_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${GNUTLS_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

add_executable(pix2image src/pix2image.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pix2image
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
  -lpthread
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253629/linking-boost-components---catkin-error/) by [mr101470](https://answers.ros.org/users/29234/mr101470/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was solved by adding the following line in the beginning

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK=1)
```

and also changing `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` to `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` (Note: "DIRS" not "DIR") as per the wiki page on [CMakeLists](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt).

---

Originally posted by [mr101470](https://answers.ros.org/users/29234/mr101470/) with karma: 46 on 2017-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2